# Partial Fraction Decomposition of $\frac{x^4+2}{x^5+6x^3}$

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I tried answering the following question but I'm getting it wrong for some reason. I would appreciate any help.

$$\frac{x^4+2}{x^5+6x^3}$$

My answer:

$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^3}+\frac{Fx+G}{x^2+6}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get $x+5$ and $x-5$? Can you show your working?

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong answer from my notepad. Just fixed it

Comment: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E4%2B2%29%2F%28x%5E5%2B6x%5E3%29) and press show steps near "Partial fraction expansion"

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to deal with $(x+b)^n$ in the denominator is to have the terms

$$ \frac{A_1}{x+b} + \frac{A_2}{(x+b)^2} + \dots + \frac{A_n}{(x+b)^n}$$

Note that $A_2$, $A_3$ etc are *constant* terms.

In your case, try expressing it in the form

$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x^3}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+6}$$

Comment: Okay, I typed in your answer and got the question correct but now I'm confused: Why did you make "Dx+E" a numerator for x^2+6? ...And under what circumstances do you put 2 constants in the numerator (i.e. when would it be okay to have something like Fx+G in the numerator)?

Comment: @mathisnotmyforte: Normally when you have a quadratic term like $x^2 + ax + b$ you put a linear term in the numerator.

Comment: @mathisnotmyforte: You use *constants* when the numerator is a power of a degree one polynomial; you use *linear* numerators when the denominator is a (power of a) irreducible quadratic.

Comment: When you have a quadratic term that has no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with a repeated factor in the denominator, such as your $x^3$:

1. You can put a *single* fraction, with denominator the full repeated factor, and undetermined denominator of degree one less. In your example, since the denominator factors as $x^3(x^2+6)$, you would set up the partial fractions as
   $$\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3} + \frac{Dx+E}{x^2+6}.$$
2. While the above works, for the purposes of integration you will then proceed to split up the first fraction and deal with it as
   $$\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3} = \frac{Ax^2}{x^3} + \frac{Bx}{x^3} + \frac{C}{x^3} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x^3};$$
   so the second way of dealing with repeated factors is to simply to that to being with: if you have a repeated factor $(x-a)^n$, you set it up with $n$ fractions, each with **constant** numerator:
   $$\frac{A_1}{x-a} + \frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2}+\cdots+\frac{A_n}{(x-a)^n};$$
   with a repeated irreducible quadratic factor, $(x^2+ax+b)^n$, it's
   $$\frac{A_1x+B_1}{x^2+ax+b} + \frac{A_2x+B_2}{(x^2+ax+b)^2} + \cdots + \frac{A_nx+B_n}{(x^2+ax+b)^n}.$$
   In your case, with $x^3$, you would set up that part as
   $$\frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x^3}.$$

Mind you: if you do the algebra right with your set-up, you *will* get the right answer; you'll just work a lot harder, and end up with the conclusion that $B=D=0$.

Comment: +1: And on a side topic, I think there have been too many partial fraction questions. It might be time for an abstract duplicate. I am pretty sure you have a great answer lying around, which can, with some modifications (to cater to a general question) serve to be the parent answer. Would you be willing to do it (i.e. modify a question and your answer appropriately?)

Comment: Maybe I can add the general method to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/21112/742)...

Comment: That looks promising!