# Integrating Reciprocals of Polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

I have seen integrals of the form $$\int \frac{1}{ax+b}dx$$ and $$\int \frac{1}{ax^{2}+bx+c} dx$$
But I cannot see how to integrate reciprocals of higher degree - does there exist a general solution to the integrals of reciprocals of cubics, quartics, and higher?

Comment: Partial Fractions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction

Comment: I wonder how you propose to do, say, $\int(x^4+1)^{-1}\,dx$ by substitution. Surely not $u=x^2$, $du=2x\,dx$ leading to $\int(2\sqrt u(u^2+1))^{-1}\,du$?

Comment: Well spotted, I hadn't actually imagined making the substitution. I'll correct the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reciprocals of higher degree can have their denominators factored into linear and/or irreducible quadratic terms, and from there, our result can be obtained through partial fraction decomposition.

For more details, see Arturo's excellent answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work/21112#21112).

Comment: Note that just because we know a partial-fraction decomposition exists doesn't mean that we can explicitly express the coefficients of that decomposition (any better than 'the $n$th root of the polynomial $p(x)$', at least); this is a consequence of Galois' famous result that polynomials of degree higher than 4 may have solutions not expressible through radicals.  So we can say what form the integral will take, but not necessarily explicitly express the result 'elementarily'.

Comment: That's a good point, Steven.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the **coefficients** of the polynomial $f(x)$ are **real**: if they're not, the question will be answered quite differently.

Every **root** of the polyomial must then either be *real* or part of a pair of complex conjugates $a\pm bi$, where $a$ and $b$ are real.

Then
$$
f(x) = c(x-\bullet)(x-\bullet)(x-\bullet)\cdots(x-\bullet)
$$
where $c$ is the leading coefficient and each "$\bullet$" is one of the roots.  If you get a real root, you've got a first-degree factor $(x-\bullet)$.  If you get a pair of conjugates, then you have something like
$$
(x - (3+5i)) (x - (3-5i)).
$$
When you multiply this out, the imaginary parts cancel:
$$
(x - (3+5i)) (x - (3-5i)) = x^2 - 3x - 5ix -3x + 5ix + 9 + 15i - 15i + 25
$$
$$
= 3x^2 - 6x + 34.
$$
There you have a quadratic factor.

**So you just get first-and second-degree factors.**

(Finding just what those factors are, in the case of, e.g. a 15th-degree polynomial, can be quite a lot of work.)

How do we know that $f(x)$ factors as
$$
c(x-\bullet)(x-\bullet)(x-\bullet)\cdots(x-\bullet)\  ?
$$
That goes back to Carl Gauss in the year 1799.  It is sometimes called the fundamental theorem of algebra, a name that some people object to on the grounds that it's a misnomer.

Comment: how can we for example factor x^4+1 into 1st and 2nd degree    since it's factors are $((-1)^{(1/4)}-x) ((-1)^{(3/4)}-x) (x+(-1)^{(1/4)}) (x+(-1)^{(3/4)})$

Comment: since when we multiply conjugates $((-1)^{(1/4)}-x)$ and $ (x+(-1)^{(1/4)})$ we get $-x^2+i$

Answer (score 0):

The general cubic cannot be done as single-summation series for except for certain cases, assuming a non-trivial factorization

For example it has the special values,

$$f(z)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{-1}{x^3-2x^2+x-z}dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^3-x^2+z}dx,,$$ which equals

$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \frac{(1)_{m} (1)_{2m}}{ z^{m+1} (2)_{3m}}.
$$

For certain $z$ this  factors into a rational linear term and a quadratic, so we obtain arctan

The reciprocal of a general cubic integral for some f(z) requires a double summation using the incomplete beta function integral