# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\,\Bbb dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate the following integral
$$
\tag1\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\,\Bbb dx
$$

---

**My Attempt:**

Letting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ and using the property that

$$
\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,\Bbb dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)\,\Bbb dx
$$

we obtain

$$
\tag2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan x}{\left(1+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^2\right)(1+\tan x)}\,\Bbb dx
$$

Now, add equation $(1)$ and $(2)$. After that I do not understand how I can proceed further.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed  solution. The numerical value is $\approx 0.597382$.

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: I did not rembember but i have seen somewere in internet

Comment: Not sure about a closed form, but maybe this will help,

$$\int \frac{1}{\left( 1 + x^2 \right) \left( 1 + \tan{x} \right)} = \arctan{x} - \int \frac{\sin{x}}{\left( x^2 + 1 \right) \left( \cos{x} + \sin{x} \right)}$$

Comment: Also, I can add a few more digits onto the numerical value $\approx 0.597381809452$

Comment: @JacobMayle: I don't think your integration by parts is correct.

Comment: @RonGordon Really? I'm pretty sure that its correct. Though, I doubt its utility.

Comment: @JacobMayle: I thought it would be $$\frac{\arctan{x}}{1+\tan{x}} + \int dx \frac{\arctan{x} \sec^2{x}}{(1+\tan{x})^2}$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha just gives a "numerical result": $\color{#ff0000}{\large\ 0.597382\ }$. I suspect there is not any analytical result!!!.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%281%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2B%5Ctan+x%29%7D+dx

Comment: I twiddled and got $\int_0^{\arctan(\pi/2)} {d\theta\over 1 + \tan(\tan(\theta))}$.  This has a certain intransigent ugliness to it.

Comment: This integral don't have any closed form. Integrals like \tan(tan(x)) are not soluble.

Comment: I don't have a closed form but I'm able to represent the integral as a series:
$$\frac{\arctan(\frac{\pi}{2}) - t\log\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}}{1+t^2}
+ \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{
(2n+1)\left(\log(n+\frac{3}{4})-\log(n+\frac{1}{4})\right)
}{
\left(1+\pi^2(n+\frac{1}{4})^2\right)\left(1+\pi^2(n+\frac{3}{4})^2\right)
}$$
where $t = \tanh(1)$. I hope someone can simplify this further. BTW, summing the first $10^4$ term gives me 0.59738180945178, a number consistent with what Jacob got.

Comment: By approximating the sum for $n > 5000$ using its Taylor expansion at $\infty$ up to terms of order $\frac{1}{n^7}$, the updated numerical value is $0.597381809451803484613113XX$ where the last two digits satisfy $23 \le XX \le 86$.

Comment: Does a u-substitution u = (1 + tan(x)) not work?

Comment: Ron's answer above can be further simplified to $$\int_0^{\pi\over2}\frac{\arctan x}{1+\sin(2x)}dx$$

Comment: This integral is improper since $tan(pi/2)$ undefined. So, you must change the integral to:
$\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\,\mathrm dx : R \rightarrow (\pi/2)^- $

Comment: Is $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)\,\mathrm dx$ given? @juantheron

Comment: @Lucian: by exploiting the symmetry around $x=\pi/4$ of the denominator, the integral can be represented also like: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\pi/2}{(1-\pi^2/16)+x^2}\right)}{\cos^2 x}dx=$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi/2}{(1-\pi^2/16)+\arctan^2 x}\right)dx.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: What (approach) do you have in mind ?

Comment: @Lucian: I would like to manipulate the integral in order to write it as a series of integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{1}\arctan\left(\frac{\log(1-v)}{2\pi z}\right)\frac{dv}{v}$, for which the Binet second log-Gamma formula works well.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: [What's stopping you](http://www.visiblemeasures.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nike-just-do-it.jpg) ? :-)

Comment: Here's a suggestion that might be of some help: Let $I$ be the required integral. Then I can prove that $2I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{2}{1-\tan^2 x} \,dx$. The identities $\tan(\pi/4 \pm x) = \frac{1 \pm \tan x}{1 \mp\tan x}$ might be of some help?

Comment: This question sure has generated a lot of junk responses. It must look a lot easier than it is.

Comment: The mathematical value of this question is nil, so how come it has not been deleted?

Comment: Just wondering... What if the original question had a tiny $^{-1}$ after the $\tan$?

Comment: In that case, the upper limit should've been $\infty$, not $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: @achille hui: Please post your answer with the procedure. We are waiting for your great answer!

Comment: Have you ever thought of cross-posting this on *Math Overflow* ?

Comment: achille hui how did you represent the integral as series?

Comment: What a train wreck. Who could've known, after so many good questions with impossible looking integrals that have been evaluated regardless that we could have such a bad one!

Comment: Although I'm not sure of this, I remember hearing somewhere that integrals containing tan(tan(x)) could not be evaluated. That makes me think that this integral too doesn't have any closed form solution. The ugliness of the series form too makes me think this won't work.

Comment: I think this is a typo; tan should perhaps be arctan in the question. Then things makes sense.

Comment: I tried on **Mathematica 9**. I got a closed form result to this impossible integral, which every one of us trying. (2 $\sqrt{3} \pi + \log{64})/18$

Comment: @lavkush No, that can't be right, it doesn't agree with the numerical value of the integral.

Comment: Not sure it is helpful or not. Since $atan(x)$'s derivative is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, have you consider integral by parts?

Comment: This question is highly amusing because of its illustration of the difficulty of finding analytic solutions to definite integrals as an open problem more than the question itself. We have the Risch algorithm to find if an expression has a closed form solution in elementary functions that mostly works (except for the constant problem) but all we have for searching for analytic solutions to definite integrals with no closed form antiderivative is heuristics rather than an actual algorithm. Axiom is the only CAS I know of that has fully implemented Risch.

Comment: I think we need to go with contour integration..

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: We may write \begin{align}
 \int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{dx}}{{\left( {1 + x^2 } \right)\left( {1 + \tan x} \right)}}}  &= \int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{\cos x}}{{\left( {1 + x^2 } \right)\left( {\cos x + \sin x} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{\cos x - \sin x}}{{\cos x - \sin x}}dx}  \\ 
  &= \int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{\cos ^2 x - \sin x\cos x}}{{\left( {1 + x^2 } \right)\cos 2x}}dx}  \\ 
  &= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{\sec 2x}}{{1 + x^2 }}dx}  + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{1}{{1 + x^2 }}dx}  - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi /2} {\frac{{\tan 2x}}{{1 + x^2 }}dx}  
 \end{align}

Comment: Can anyone find closed forms for @mwomath's 1st and 3rd integrals?

Comment: I think we can use series. $$1/(1+x^2)=\sum (-1)^k x^{2k},$$ $$\tan x =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{k-1}\frac{2^{2k}(2^{2k}-1) B_{2k}}{(2k)!} x^{2k- 1}} $$ where $ B_{2k} $ are thé Bernoulli numbers, and I don't know a closed expansion of $\sec x $ if anybody help?!

Comment: @mwomath Very similar to the $\tan$ series, with Euler numbers instead: $\sec x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{|E_{2k}|}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$. Good luck!

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 249):

Here is an approach.

We give some preliminary results.

---

### **The poly-Hurwitz zeta function**

---

The poly-Hurwitz zeta function may  initially be defined  by the series
$$
\begin{align}
  \displaystyle \zeta(s\mid a,b) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}, 
  \quad \Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1, \, \Re s>0. \tag1
\end{align} 
$$
This special function is a natural extension of the [Hurwitz zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11) initially defined as
$$
\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^s}, \quad \Re a>0, \Re s>1, \tag2
$$ 
which is a natural extension itself of the [Riemann zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2) initially defined as
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}, \quad \Re s>1. \tag3
$$

The poly-Hurwitz function appears in different places with different notations, one may find it here:
 [[Masri](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/riad/Herglotz-ZagierFinal.pdf), p. 2 and p. 15  (2004)], [[Murty](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/murty-sinha.pdf), p. 17 (2006)], [[Sinha](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~kaneenika/MSc-thesis.pdf), p. 45 (2002)]. In this answer we are dealing with a simplified version of a general poly-Hurwitz function.

The series in $(1)$ converges absolutely for $\displaystyle \Re s>0$. Moreover, the convergence of the series is uniform on every
half-plane $$\displaystyle H_{\delta}=\left\{s \in \mathbb{C}, \Re s \geq  \delta \right\}, \, \delta \in \mathbb{R},\, \delta>0,$$ therefore the poly-Hurwitz zeta function $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot \mid a,b)$
is analytic on the half-plane $\displaystyle \Re s>0$.

Let $a$, $b$ and $s$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1, \, \Re s >0$. One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
  \zeta(s\mid a,b) & =  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}\\
 & = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(n+b)+(a-b)}{(n+a)^{s+1}(n+b)}\\
 & = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s+1}}+(a-b)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s+1}(n+b)} \tag4
\end{align} 
$$
giving the functional identity
$$
\begin{align}
 \zeta(s \mid a,b) = \zeta(s+1,a+1) +(a-b) \zeta(s+1 \mid a,b) \tag5
\end{align} 
$$

where $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the standard Hurwitz zeta function.

From $(5)$, we obtain by induction, for $n=1,2,3,\ldots $,

$$
\begin{align}
 \zeta(s\mid a,b) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a-b)^{k-1}\zeta(s+k,a+1) +(a-b)^n\zeta(s+n \mid a,b). \tag6
\end{align} 
$$

We use $(6)$ to extend $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot \mid a,b)$ to a meromorphic function on each open set $\Re s>-n $, $n\geq 1$. Since the Hurwitz zeta function is analytic on the whole complex plane except for a simple pole at $1$ with residue $1$, then from $(6)$ the poly-Hurwitz zeta function $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot\mid a,b)$ is analytic on the whole complex plane except for a simple pole at $0$ with residue $1$.

---

### **The poly-Stieltjes constants**

---

In 1885 Stieltjes has found  that the Laurent series expansion around $1$ of the Riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta(1+s) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k s^k, \quad s \neq 0,\tag7
$$  is such that the coefficients of the regular part of the expansion are given by
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma_k& = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^k n}{n}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right).
\end{align} \tag8
$$ Euler was the first to define a constant of this form (1734)
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma & = \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1N-\log N\right)=0.577215\ldots.
\end{align} 
$$ The constants $\displaystyle \gamma_k$ are called the *Stieltjes constants* and due to the fact that $\displaystyle \gamma_0=\gamma$   they are sometimes called the *generalized Euler's constants*.

Similarly, Wilton (1927) and Berndt (1972) established that the  Laurent series expansion in the  neighbourhood of $1$ of the Hurwitz zeta function 
$$
\begin{align} \zeta(1+s,a) 
= \frac1s+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}(a)\:s^{k}, \quad \Re a>0, \,s\neq 0, \tag{9}
\end{align}
$$ is such that the coefficients of the regular part of the expansion are given by
$$
\begin{align} 
\gamma_k(a)& = \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{\log^k (n+a)}{n+a}-\frac{\log^{k+1} (N+a)}{k+1}\right), \quad \Re a>0,
\end{align} \tag{10}
$$ 
with $\displaystyle \gamma_{0}(a)=-\psi(a)=-\Gamma'(a)/\Gamma(a)$. The coefficients $\gamma_k(a)$ are called the *generalized Stieltjes constants*.

We have seen from $(6)$ that the poly-Hurwitz zeta function admits a Laurent series expansion around $0$. Let's denote by $\displaystyle\gamma_k(a,b)$ the coefficients of the regular part of $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot\mid a,b)$ around $0$. I will call these coefficients the *poly-Stieltjes constants*.

Do we have an analog of $(10)$ for $\displaystyle\gamma_k(a,b)$?

The following result is new.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $a,b$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1$. Consider 
>   The poly-Hurwitz zeta function $$
> \begin{align}
>    \zeta(s\mid a,b) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}, 
>   \quad \Re s>0. \tag{11}
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   Then the meromorphic extension of $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot\mid a,b)$ admits the following Laurent series expansion around $0$,
>   $$
> \zeta(s \mid a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k(a,b) s^k, \quad s \neq 0,\tag{12}
> $$ where the poly-Stieltjes constants $\displaystyle \gamma_k(a,b)$ are given by $$
> \begin{align} 
> \gamma_k(a,b)& = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^k (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right)
> \end{align} \tag{13}
> $$ with $$ \gamma_{0}(a,b)=-\psi(b+1)=-\Gamma'(b+1)/\Gamma(b+1). \tag{14}$$

*Proof.* Let $a,b$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1$.

We first assume $\Re s>0$. Observing that, for each $n \geq 1$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}s^k\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\right|\frac{|s|^k }{k!}<\infty
$$ and that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}s^k\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac1{(n+a)^s(n+b)}\right| = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{|n+a|^{\Re s}|n+b|}<\infty,$$
we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right)  s^k \\\\
&= \lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right) s^k \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}s^k -\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}s^k\right) \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^k(n+a)}{n+b}s^k -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}s^k\right) \\\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{(n+a)^s(n+b)} +\frac1{N^s}-\frac1s\right) \\\\
&=\zeta(s \mid a,b)-\frac1{s}
\end{align}
$$  as desired. Then, using $(6)$, we extend the preceding identity by analytic continuation  to all $s \neq 0$. To prove $(14)$, we start from a standard series representation of the digamma function (see [Abram. & Steg. p. 258](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) 6.3.16):
$$
\begin{align}
-\psi(b+1) &= \gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac1n - \frac1{b+n}  \right) \\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^N\left( \frac1n - \frac1{b+n}  \right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{b+n} -\ln N\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n-\ln N-\gamma \right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{b+n} -\ln N\right)\\\\
&=\gamma_0(a,b)
\end{align} 
$$ using $(13)$.

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

---

One of the consequences of **Theorem 1** is the new possibility to express some series in terms of the poly-Stieltjes constants.

> **Theorem 2.** Let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1, \, \Re c >-1$.
>
> Then 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>   (b-a)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\log (n+c)}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\gamma_1(c,a)-\gamma_1(c,b), \tag{15}
> \end{align} 
> $$ similarly
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac1{n+b}\left({\log (n+a)-\log (n+c)}\right)=\gamma_1(a,b)-\gamma_1(c,b), \tag{16}
> \end{align} 
> $$ with the poly-Stieltjes constant
>   $$\gamma_1(a,b) = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right). 
> $$

*Proof.* Let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a >-1, \, \Re b >-1, \, \Re c >-1$.

We have
$$
 (b-a)\frac{\log (n+c)}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\log (n+c)}{n+a}-\frac{\log (n+c)}{n+b}
$$ giving, for $N\geq1$,
$$
\begin{align}
  (b-a)&\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+c)}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\\\\
&  \left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log (n+c)}{n+a}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log (n+c)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right) \tag{17}
\end{align}
$$
letting $N \to \infty$  and  using $(13)$ gives $(15)$.

We have, for $N\geq1$,
$$
\begin{align}
  &\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n+b}\left({\log (n+a)-\log (n+c)}\right)\\\\
&=  \left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\log (n+c)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right) \tag{18}
\end{align}
$$
letting $N \to \infty$ and  using $(13)$ gives $(16)$.

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

---

### **Juantheron's integral**

---

Let’s first give a numerical evaluation of Juantheron’s integral.

I would like to thank [Jonathan Borwein and David H. Bailey](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbsoftware/) who obtained the result below to $1000$ digits, in just 3.9 seconds run time, using David's new MPFUN-MPFR software, along with the [tanh-sinh quadrature](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/hp-num-int.pdf) program included with the MPFUN-MPFR  package.

They also tried the integral with David's MPFUN-Fort package, which has a completely different underlying multiprecision system, and they obtained the same result below.

Finally, they computed the integral with *Mathematica* $11.0$;  it agreed with the result below, although it required about 10 times longer to run.

> **Proposition 1.** We have
>   $$
> \begin{align}  \int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}2}\!&\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\mathrm dx\\\\=
> 0.&59738180945180348461311323509087376430643859042555\\
> &67307703207161550311033249824121789098990404474443\\
> &73300942847961727020952797366230453350097928752529\\
> &62099371263365268445580755896768905606293308536674\\
> &89639352215352393870280616186538538722285601087082\\
> &81730013060929540132583577240799018025603130403772\\
> &83596189879605956759516344861849456740112012597646\\
> &30195536341071109827787231788650530475635336662512\\
> &50757672078320586388500276160658476344052492489409\\
> &64026178233152015087197531148322444147655936720008 \tag{19}\\
> &40650450631581050321100329502169853063154902765446\\
> &58804861176982696627707544105655815406116180984371\\
> &54148587721902800400109013880620460529382772599713\\
> &06874977209651994186527207589425408866256042399213\\
> &80515694164361264997143539392018681691584285790381\\
> &65536517701019826846772718498479534803417547866296\\
> &23842162877309354675086691711521468623807334908897\\
> &71491673168051054009130049879837629516862688171756\\
> &13790927986073268994254629238035029442300668334396\\
> &901581838911515359223628586133156893962372426055\cdots
> \end{align}
> $$

David H. Bailey confirmed that *Mathematica* $11.0$, in spite of the great numerical precision, could not find a closed-form of the integral.

The next result proves that the OP integral admits a closed form in terms of the poly-Stieltjes constants.

> **Proposition 2.** We have
>   $$
> \begin{align}  \int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}2}\!\!\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\mathrm dx
> &=\frac{(e^2+1)^2}{2(e^4+1)}\arctan \! \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{e^4-1}{4(e^4+1)}\log\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)\\\\
> &+\frac{64 \pi^2\log 3}{(\pi^2+16)(9\pi^2+16)} \\\\
> &+\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac34 +\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac34 +\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right)\tag{20}\\\\ &+\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac14 -\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac14 -\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right)
> \end{align}
> $$ with the poly-Stieltjes constant 
>   $$\gamma_1(a,b) = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right). $$

*Proof.* We  proceed in three steps.

**Step 1.** One may write
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{(1+x^2)(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\cos x+\sin x)+(\cos x-\sin x)}{(1+x^2)(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\!\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx+\frac12\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)}{(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12 \arctan\! \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac12\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\tan (x-\pi/4)\:\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12 \arctan\! \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac12\int_{-\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\frac{1}{1+(x+\pi/4)^2}\tan x \:\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12 \arctan\! \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac12\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\left(\frac1{1+(x+\pi/4)^2}-\frac1{1+(x-\pi/4)^2}\right)\tan x \:\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12 \arctan\! \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\Im}2 \!\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\!\!\left(\!\frac1{x+\pi/4+i}+\frac1{x-\pi/4-i}\!\right) \tan x \:\mathrm dx \tag{21}
\end{align}
$$
Let’s evaluate the latter integral.

**Step 2.** One may recall that the tangent function, as a meromorphic function, can be expressed as [an infinite sum of rational functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11):
$$
\tan x = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{2x}{\pi^2 (n+1/2)^2-x^2}, \quad x \neq \pm \pi/2, \pm 3\pi/2,\pm 5\pi/2,\ldots. \tag{22}
$$
We have the inequality
$$
\sup_{x \in [0,\pi/4]}\left|\frac{2x}{\pi^2 (n+1/2)^2-x^2}\right|\leq \frac1{(n+1/2)^2}, \quad n=0,1,2,\ldots, \tag{23}
$$ the convergence in $(22)$ is then uniform on  $[0,\pi/4]$. Thus, plugging $(22)$ into $(21)$, we are allowed to integrate $(21)$ termwise.

Each term, via a partial fraction decomposition, is evaluated to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}4}\!&\left(\!\frac1{x+\pi/4+i}+\frac1{x-\pi/4-i}\!\right)\frac{2x}{\pi^2 (n+1/2)^2-x^2}\:\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{2\tau}{\pi^2 (n+1/2)^2-\tau^2}\log \left( \frac{4\tau-\pi}{4\tau+\pi}\right)\\
&+\frac1{\pi}\frac1{(n+1/2+\tau/\pi)}\left(\log\!\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\!\left(n+\frac14\right) \right)\\
&+\frac1{\pi}\frac1{(n+1/2-\tau/\pi)}\left(\log\!\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\!\left(n+\frac14\right) \right)
\end{align} \tag{24}
$$
where for the sake of convenience we have set $\tau:=\pi/4+i$.

**Step 3.** We sum $(24)$ from $n=0$ to $\infty$ obtaining

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\!&\left(\!\frac1{x+\pi/4+i}+\frac1{x-\pi/4-i}\!\right) \tan x \:\mathrm dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\tau}{\pi^2 (n+1/2)^2-\tau^2}\log \left( \frac{4\tau-\pi}{4\tau+\pi}\right)\\
&+\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+1/2+\tau/\pi)}\left(\log\!\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\!\left(n+\frac14\right) \right)\\
&+\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+1/2-\tau/\pi)}\left(\log\!\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\!\left(n+\frac14\right) \right), \tag{25}
\end{align}
$$ then, singling out the first terms in the two last series and using **Theorem $2$ $(16)$**, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}}\!&\left(\!\frac1{x+\pi/4+i}+\frac1{x-\pi/4-i}\!\right) \tan x \:\mathrm dx\\
&=\tan \tau \log \left( \frac{4\tau-\pi}{4\tau+\pi}\right)
+\frac{4\pi}{\pi^2 -4\tau^2}\log 3
\\&+\frac1{\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac12 +\frac{\tau}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac1{\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac12 +\frac{\tau}{\pi}\!\right)\tag{26}\\ &+\frac1{\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac12 -\frac{\tau}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac1{\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac12 -\frac{\tau}{\pi}\!\right)
\end{align} $$ and the substitution $\tau=\pi/4+i$ gives the desired result.

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

---

**Achille Hui's conjecture is true**.

Achille Hui has announced in the comments that the OP integral is equal to 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\arctan(\frac{\pi}{2}) - t\log\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi^2}{4}}}{1+t^2}+\frac{\pi^2}4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{ (2n+1)\left(\log\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\left(n+\frac14\right)\right) }{ \left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac14\right)^2\right)\left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac34\right)^2\right) } \tag{27}
\end{align}
$$ with $\displaystyle t := \tanh(1)$.

The first term in $(27)$, with a little algebra is seen  to be equal to the sum of the first two terms on the right hand side of $(20)$.

We establish the veracity of the conjecture using **Proposition $2$** and using the next result.

> **Proposition 3.** We have
>   $$
> \begin{align}  &\frac{\pi^2}4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{ (2n+1)\left(\log\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\left(n+\frac14\right)\right) }{ \left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac14\right)^2\right)\left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac34\right)^2\right) }\\\\
> &=\frac{64 \pi^2\log 3}{(\pi^2+16)(9\pi^2+16)} \\\\
> &+\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac34 +\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac34 +\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right)\tag{28}\\\\ &+\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac34,\frac14 -\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right) -\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\gamma_1\!\left(\!\frac14,\frac14 -\frac{i}{\pi}\!\right)
> \end{align}
> $$ with the poly-Stieltjes constant 
>   $$\gamma_1(a,b) = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right).$$

*Proof.* Observe that the first term of the series on the left hand side of  $(28)$, given by $n=0$, is just equal to
$$
\frac{64 \pi^2\log 3}{(\pi^2+16)(9\pi^2+16)}.
$$ By a partial fraction decomposition, one may check that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}4 &\frac{ (2n+1) }{ \left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac14\right)^2\right)\left(1+\pi^2\left(n+\frac34\right)^2\right) }
=\frac{\Im}{2\pi}\left(\!\frac1{n+\frac34+\frac{i}{\pi}}-\frac1{n+\frac14+\frac{i}{\pi}}\!\right) \tag{29}
\end{align}
$$ 
then, multiplying $(29)$ by $\left(\log\!\left(n+\frac34\right)-\log\!\left(n+\frac14\right)\right)$ and summing from $n=1$ to $\infty$ we get, using **Theorem $2$ $(16)$**, the result $(28)$.

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

---

Comment: @Lucian I've evaluated your challenging integral :-)

Comment: Defining enough special functions everything can be written in closed-form. I'm not convinced this is the simplest form one can get.

Comment: Je ne l'avais pas encore vu celle-là. Cela m'amuse toujours de voir la qualité de vos réponses et l'aisance qu'il semble s'y dégager même si j'imagine que celle-ci a dû vous prendre au moins trente minutes. :)

Comment: @Waiting Then, instead of writing useless comments, work smart and find a better solution. At least he gave a closed form, no matter if they do involve special functions, which by the way are very useful also because of this use.

Comment: @VonNeumann Maybe useless for you, but good to keep in mind for people that are always interested in digging deeper (which obviously doesn't seem to be your case). My inuition keeps me away from being convinced this is the simplest closed-form. That simple.

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa Another, very compact, form of the integral is $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \text{arctan}(\text{arctan}(z+\frac{\pi}{4}))$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Observe that $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \text{arctan}(\text{arctan}(z+\frac{\pi}{4}))\mathrm dz=0.363033\cdots$ whereas $\int_{0}^{\large\frac{\pi}2}\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\mathrm dx=0.5973818\cdots$.

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa: no, sorry, Mathematica gives $ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 \text{arctan}\left(\text{arctan}(z)+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \, dz = 0.5973818094518034846131132350908737643064...$. The formula follows from partial integration, leading to $\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \text{arctan}\left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sec ^2(y) \, dy$, and subsequent substitution $z\to \tan(y)$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Sorry but, as you can see, you have changed the integrand between the first and the last comment:)

Comment: @ Olivier Oloa, your are right. I missed the typo in my first comment. What I wanted to point out is the correct formula in the second comment (with the derivation).

Comment: @OlivierOloa  What accuracy have you achieved?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Thank you. It seems all digits in **Proposition 1** above are correct.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you too. As it is shown in my answer, tricky series summation via Wolfram Alpha gives near 30 decimal digits.

Answer (score 44):

**Too long for a comment:** It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401) that $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin(\cos x)dx=\frac\pi2H_0(1)$,

and $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos(\cos x)dx=\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos(\sin x)dx=\frac\pi2J_0(1)$, where *H* and *J* are the [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Definitions) and [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Definitions)

functions respectively, so it is not out of the question that the existence of such closed forms, at

least in terms of these special functions, might have been one of the main initial triggers which

determined our [anonymous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xJFT.png) source to investigate the nature of $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\!\tan(\tan x)dx$, which turns

out to be $\ldots$ rather difficult, to say the very least. Indeed, the entire interval $\bigg(0,\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$ can be

broken up into an infinite number of sub-intervals, the first one of which is $\bigg(0,~\arctan\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$,

while all others are of the form $\bigg[\arctan\bigg(\dfrac\pi2+k\pi\bigg),~\arctan\bigg(\dfrac\pi2+\big(k+1\big)\pi\bigg)\bigg]$, for $k\in$ **N**.

The integral diverges towards $+\infty$ on the former, and towards $-\infty$ on the rest, but in such

a manner that $\displaystyle\int_0^{\alpha(k)}\!\tan(\tan x)dx\to\infty$ rather than $-\infty$, where $\alpha(k)=\arctan\bigg(\dfrac\pi2+k\pi\bigg)$.

This can be better visualized by plotting the function's [graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcatC.jpg). But determining whether the

limit $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^{\alpha(k)}\!\tan(\tan x)dx$ ultimately converges or diverges is by no means a trivial task

$\big($indeed, it is quite daunting$\big)$, so, discouraged, either by the integral's probable divergence, or

perhaps by its difficulty, or maybe by a bit of both, our anonymous source $\big($let's call him/her

Person X$\big)$ decides to focus its attention now on $\bigg(0,~\arctan\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$, but not before changing the

function into $~\dfrac1{\tan(\tan x)}$ , so as to avoid its divergence in $x=\arctan\dfrac\pi2$ . However, he now

faces another problem: its divergence in $0$. In order to fix this new impediment, the function

is further changed to $~\dfrac1{1+\tan(\tan x)}$ . Then, by a simple substitution, $\displaystyle\int_0^{\alpha(0)}\frac{dx}{1+\tan(\tan x)}$

becomes $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$ , as already pointed out by **ncmathsadist** in the comment

section above. That such an improvised integral would indeed have a meaningful closed form

is no more likelier than for $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dx}{1+\sin(\sin x)}=\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dx}{1+\sin(\cos x)}$ or $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dx}{1+\cos(\cos x)}$

$=\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dx}{1+\cos(\sin x)}$ to possess one as well.

Answer (score 16):

It is clear that the integral cannot be expressed in the form of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). This is another approach expanding on mwomath's comment. I feel this approach may be useful as it is a bit easier to understand in my opinion, as compared to Olivier Oloa's answer (which is completely fine). Sorry in advance for any steps I miss.

## Simplifying the original integral into three integrals:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$$ $$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x dx}{(1+x^2)(\sin x+\cos x)}$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x dx}{(1+x^2)(\sin x+\cos x)}.\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)}{(\cos x-\sin x)}$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x-\sin x \cos x }{(1+x^2)(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x-\sin x \cos x }{(1+x^2)(\cos 2x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2\cos^2 x-1-2\sin x \cos x+1) }{(1+x^2)(\cos 2x)}dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{(\cos 2x-\sin 2x+1) }{(1+x^2)(\cos 2x)}dx$$

> $$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec 2x}{1+x^2}dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan 2x}{1+x^2}dx$$

---

## Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$ :

We know that $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\arctan x$

> So, $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\arctan (\pi/2)$$

---

## Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec 2x}{1+x^2}dx$ :

The infinite sum of $\sec x$ is given as:

$$\sec x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{U_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
where $U_{n}$ [up/down number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up/down_number).

Similarly,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec 2x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n.U_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!(1+x^2)}dx= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2^{2n}.U_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!(1+x^2)}dx$$
$$\int \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\left( 1+\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}(-x^2)+\frac{2n+1}{2n+5}(-x^2)^2-\frac{2n+1}{2n+7}(-x^2)^6+\cdots\right)$$

We can express the infinite sum in the parenthesis in form of the [hyper-geometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html):

$$_2F_1 \left(1, n+\frac{1}{2}; n+\frac{3}{2} ; -x^2 \right)$$

> So,
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec 2x}{1+x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2^{2n}.U_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!(1+x^2)}dx$$
>   $$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n}.U_{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{(\pi/2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}._2F_1 \left(1, n+\frac{1}{2}; n+\frac{3}{2} ; -\pi^2/4 \right)$$

---

## Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan 2x}{1+x^2}dx$ :

The infinite sum of $\tan x$ is given as:
$$\tan x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{U_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
where $U_{n}$ [up/down number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up/down_number).

Similarly,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan 2x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!(1+x^2)}dx= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!(1+x^2)}dx$$
$$\int \frac{x^{2n+1}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2}\left( 1+\frac{2n+2}{2n+4}(-x^2)+\frac{2n+2}{2n+6}(-x^2)^2-\frac{2n+2}{2n+8}(-x^2)^6+\cdots\right)$$

We can express the infinite sum in the parenthesis in form of the [hyper-geometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html):

$$_2F_1 \left(1, n+1; n+2 ; -x^2 \right)$$

> So,
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan 2x}{1+x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!(1+x^2)}dx$$
>   $$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(\pi/2)^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)}._2F_1 \left(1, n+1; n+2 ; -\pi^2/4 \right)$$

---

## Final expression:

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$$
>   $$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n}.U_{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{(\pi/2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}._2F_1 \left(1, n+\frac{1}{2}; n+\frac{3}{2} ; -\pi^2/4 \right)$$
>   $$+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\frac{(\pi/2)^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)}._2F_1 \left(1, n+1; n+2 ; -\pi^2/4 \right)+\arctan (\pi/2) + C$$

or if you don't want to use hyper-geometric functions (in my opinion they just make the integral look a bit more clean and are a good way of representing certain infinite sums):

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}$$
>   $$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2^{2n}.U_{2n}.(\pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}(\pi/2)^{2k+1}}{2(n+k)+1} \right)$$
>   $$+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2^{2n+1}.U_{2n+1}(\pi/2)^n}{(2n+1)!} .\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(\pi/2)^{2k}}{2(n+k)}\right) +\arctan (\pi/2) + C$$

Answer (score 8):

Let us try to understand the computer-based answer of **Oliver Oloa**.

**Rational decomposition.**

Is known the rational decomposition of the trigonometric functions in the forms of
$$\tan z = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8z}{\pi^2\left(2n+1\right)^2 - 4z^2},\tag{R1}$$
$$\sec z = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{4\pi(2n+1)}{\pi^2\left(2n+1\right)^2 - 4z^2},\tag{R2}$$
with the corollaries
$$\tanh z =-i\tan(iz) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8z}{\pi^2\left(2n+1\right)^2 + 4z^2},\tag{R3}$$
$$\operatorname{sech}z = \sec(iz) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{4\pi(2n+1)}{\pi^2\left(2n+1\right)^2 + 4z^2}.\tag{R4}$$

**Preparation.**

$$I=\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\dfrac{\text dx}{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}
=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\left(\dfrac{1+\tan x}{1+\tan x}
-\dfrac{\tan x-1}{1+\tan x}\right)\,\dfrac{\text dx}{1+x^2}$$
$$=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\dfrac{\text dx}{1+x^2}
-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\tan\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)\,\dfrac{\text dx}{1+x^2},$$
$$I=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\dfrac{\text dx}{1+x^2}
-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)\,\text dx,\tag1$$
where, taking in account $(R1),$
$$g_n(x)=\dfrac{2x-\large\frac\pi2}{\pi^2\left(n+\large\frac12\right)^2 - \left(x-\large\frac\pi4\right)^2}\cdot\dfrac1{1+x^2}.\tag2$$

**Partial fractions.**

The functions $\;g_n(x)\;$ allow decomposition in the form of
$$g_n(x)=\dfrac{A_nx+B_n}{1+x^2} + \dfrac {C_n}{\pi n+\frac34\pi-x} + \dfrac {D_n}{\pi n+\frac14\pi+x}.\tag3$$
Then
$$C_n=\lim_{\large x\to \pi n+\frac34\pi}\, \left(\pi n+\frac34\pi-x\right)g_n(x)
= \dfrac{16}{(4 n\pi+3\pi)^2 +16},$$
$$D_n=\lim_{\large x\to -\pi n-\frac14\pi}\, \left(\pi n+\frac14\pi+x\right)g_n(x)
= -\dfrac{16}{(4n\pi+\pi)^2 +16},$$
$$A_n-C_n+D_n=\lim_{\large x\to \infty}\, x g_n(x) = 0,\quad A_n=C_n-D_n,$$
$$B_n+ \dfrac {C_n}{\pi n+\frac34\pi} + \dfrac {D_n}{\pi n+\frac14\pi} =g_n(0) = -\dfrac8{\pi(16n^2+16n+3)},$$
$$B_n = \dfrac4{4\pi n+3\pi} -\dfrac4{4\pi n+\pi} -  \dfrac {4C_n}{4\pi n+3\pi} - \dfrac {4D_n}{4\pi n+\pi}.$$
$$B_n = 4(4\pi n+3\pi)C_n + 4(4\pi n+\pi)D_n.$$

Let
$$U_k = \dfrac{16}{(2k\pi+\pi)^2+16},$$
then, taking in account $(R3)-(R4),$
$$D_n = -U_{2n},\quad C_n=U_{2n+1},\;$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty A_n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty U_n = \tanh2,\tag4$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B_n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}4\pi(2n+1)U_n
= -\operatorname{sech}2.\tag5$$

**Integration.**

$$I=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\dfrac{\text dx}{1+x^2}
-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^{\Large^\pi/_2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)\,\text dx$$
$$ = \dfrac12 \arctan \,\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac12\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac12 A_n \ln\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}4+1\right) +B_n \arctan \,\dfrac\pi2+(C_n+D_n) \ln\dfrac{4n + 3}{4n+1}\right),$$
$$I=-\dfrac14\tanh 2\ln\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}4+1\right) + \dfrac{1+\operatorname{sech}2}2 \arctan \,\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac12 I_1,\tag6$$
where
$$I_1=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (C_n+D_n) \ln\dfrac{4n + 3}{4n+1},\tag7$$
with the representations
$$I_1=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{128\pi^2(2n+1)}{\pi^4((4n+2)^2-1)^2 +32\pi^2((4n+2)^2+1)+256}\,\ln\dfrac{4n+3}{4n+1}\tag{7a}$$

[image: I1-S]
[image: Sum S]

and
$$I_1=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Im\left(-\dfrac4{4\pi n+3\pi+4i}+\dfrac4{4\pi n+\pi+4i}\right) \ln\dfrac{4n + 3}{4n+1}.\tag{7b}$$

**The poly-Stieltjes constants using.**

The poly-Stieltjjes constants do not belong to the standard special functions, but they are defined in the **Oliver Oloa** answer as the known specific functions.

In particular, from $(7b)$ and the given definition in the form of
$$\gamma_1(a,b) = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \dfrac{\ln(n+a)}{n+b} - \dfrac{\ln N^2}2\right)\tag{$\large\diamond$}$$
should
$$\begin{align}
&I_1= \dfrac{16}{16+9\pi^2}\,\ln3 - \dfrac1\pi \Im\left(\gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac34,\frac34+\frac i\pi\right) 
- \gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac14,\frac34+\frac i\pi\right) \right)\\[4pt]
&-\dfrac{16}{16+\pi^2}\,\ln3 + \dfrac1\pi \Im\left(\gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac34,\frac14+\frac i\pi\right) 
- \gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac14,\frac14+\frac i\pi\right) \right),
\end{align}\tag8$$

$$\begin{align}
&I=-\dfrac14\tanh 2\ln\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}4+1\right) + \dfrac{1+\operatorname{sech}2}2 \arctan \,\dfrac\pi2
+\dfrac{64\pi^2}{(16+\pi^2)(16+9\pi^2)}\\[4pt]
&+\dfrac1{2\pi}\Im\left(\gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac34,\frac34+\frac i\pi\right) 
- \gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac14,\frac34+\frac i\pi\right) \right)\\[4pt]
&- \dfrac1{2\pi} \Im\left(\gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac34,\frac14+\frac i\pi\right) 
- \gamma_1\left(\small\dfrac14,\frac14+\frac i\pi\right) \right).
\end{align}\tag9$$

Formula $(9)$ gives the closed-form representation, which cannot be used in the popular package Wolfram Alpha.

**Results.**

- Obtained the alternatiive notation of the poly-Stieltjes closed form $(9)$ for the given integral.
- Obtained the calculating formulas $(6),(7a)$ via the elementary functions series. Evaluated value

[image: Integral I]
[image: Integral I, value]

corresponds to the numerical calculations of the given integral

[image: Numerical calculations of I].

Comment: adding to your wonderful series of "tremendous" integrals (+1)!

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Great! Impressive derivation! (+1)

Comment: @Yuri is the final result the closed form for the integral?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Only (9).

Comment: I feel like the OP is a high school student who either just randomly make up an integral or copied the wrong question ☠️ No way that he encountered such an integral in a course or a project and all he could think of was king's

Answer (score 6):

A good fit for $\frac{1}{1+\tan x}$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is $1-\frac{2}{\pi}x$

So

$$I_{approx}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\frac{2}{\pi}x}{1+x^2}dx=\arctan \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\ln\left (1+ \frac{\pi^2}{4} \right )$$
Absolute error is about $0.011$

Comment: Wolfy says that 1/(1+\tan(x)) = 1 - x + x^2 - (4 x^3)/3 + (5 x^4)/3 + O(x^5).