# Hard integration problems book, special functions

Tags: integration, reference-request

I want hard integration problems which level is college competition or harder.

I want problems book about hard integration.

Would you recommend some problems books?

And can you recommend books about special function (used in graduate level)?

Comment: Too broad?${}{}{}$

Comment: If you want to be really brave, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

Comment: If you are super brave, try to integrate [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/364452). Quite a few of us here consider this to be the hardest integral on MSE.

Comment: Special functions are usually field specific, and you can find relevant ones for the field you're doing often in books titled "Mathematical Methods for ____" (usually physics), and a lot of them are in Abramowitz and Stegun and on mathworld. If you want competition level problems, find the competitions you're interested in and look at old problems or check Amazon for training books on them.

Comment: The graveyard of answers on that question is spectacular, @achillehui.