# A series with logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions

Can we express in terms of known constants the sum:

$$\mathcal{S}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{n}$$

First of all it converges , but not matter what I try or whatever technic I am about to apply it fails. In the mean time if we split it apart (let us take the partial sums) then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\log (n+1) - \log n}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\log (n+1)}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\log n}{n}$$

The last sum at the RHS does resemble a zeta function derivative taken at $1$. Of course zeta function diverges at $1$ but its PV exists, namely $\mathcal{P}(\zeta(1))=\gamma$. Maybe we have a PV for the derivative also? The other sum at the RHS is nearly the last sum at the right.

This is as much as I have noticed in this sum. Any help?

**Addendum:** I was trying to evaluate the integral:

$$\mathcal{J}=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x) \log (1-x)}{x \log x} \, {\rm d}x$$

This is what I got.

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x) \log(1-x)}{x \log x} &=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x}{x \log x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1} (1-x)}{\log x} \, {\rm d}x\\ 
 &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n-x^{n-1}}{\log x} \, {\rm d}x \\ 
 &\overset{(*)}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n+1) -\log n}{n}  \\ 
 &= ?
\end{align*}

$(*)$ since it is quite easy to see that:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^a-x^{a-1}}{\log x} \, {\rm d}x = \log (a+1) - \log a  , \; a \geq 1$$

due to DUTIES.

*Maybe someone else can tackle the integral in a different manner?*

Comment: Perhaps progress might be made by rearranging the negative terms to associate to the right instead, which gives $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n(n-1)} $?

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you! :)

Comment: Also equals $\int_0^1 H_x / x \, dx$.

Comment: Hi nospoon.. For the evaluation of the integral you mention maybe use the fact that Harmonic number is related to digamma ?

Comment: The series is equivalent to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n(n+1)}$$ If that helps anyone.

Comment: @Tolaso Pllease there is a typo in your question, it's rather $\mathcal{J}=\mathcal{S}$, not $\mathcal{J}=-\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: I'll try to fix it in a moment. Thanks Olivier

Comment: @Will: That's what I said.

Comment: @WillFisher Yes, this form is noticed in Theorem $2$ here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569

Comment: @WillFisher Yes I know realize how it all connects.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I know realize how it all connects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given series admits a closed-form in terms of the poly-Stieltjes constants. The poly-Stieltjes constants arise in the context of finding the *Laurent series expansion of the poly-Hurwitz zeta function*
$$
\begin{align}
   \zeta(s\mid a,b)= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)}, 
  \tag1
\end{align}
$$ *around* $s = 0$. One may prove that (see [Theorem $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569)), as $s \to 0$,
$$\zeta(s \mid a,b) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\gamma_k(a,b) s^k,\tag2
$$ with $$
\begin{align} 
\gamma_k(a,b)& = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log^k (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^{k+1} \!N}{k+1}\right),\tag3
\\\\ \gamma_{k}(a,a)&=\gamma_{k}(a+1),\tag4
\end{align} 
$$ where $\gamma_{k}(a+1)$ are the [generalized Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Generalized_Stieltjes_constants).

We thus obtain the following result.

> **Proposition**.
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> &\mathcal{S}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{n}=\gamma_1(1,0)-\gamma_1 \tag5
> \\\\&\mathcal{J}=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x) \log (1-x)}{x \log x} \, {\rm d}x=\gamma_1(1,0)-\gamma_1  \tag6
> \end{align}
> $$

by using [Theorem $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569) and the fact that $\mathcal{J}=\mathcal{S}$.

Answer (score 2):

We may exploit [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) to get an integral representation of our series.

$$\begin{eqnarray*}S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{n}&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{-nx}-e^{-(n+1)x}}{nx}\,dx\\ &=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\left(-\log(1-e^{-x})\right)\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log x}{(1-x)\log(1-x)}\,dx\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
In terms of [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients)
$$ \frac{x}{\log(1-x)}=-1+\sum_{n\geq 1}|G_n|x^n\tag{2}$$
gives:
$$ S = \zeta(2)+\sum_{n\geq 1}|G_n|\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n \log(x)}{1-x} \,dx = \boxed{\zeta(2)-\sum_{n\geq 1}^{\phantom{}}|G_n|\,\zeta(2,n+1)}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: +1. Nice job. You're a Frullani fan. The series looks like an innocent one whatsoever but...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\,\mathcal{S} =
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n} \over n} =\, ?}$.

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\,\mathcal{S}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n} \over n} =
\ln\pars{2} + \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n} \over n}
\\[4mm] & =
\ln\pars{2} +
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\,\ln\pars{n + 1 \over n - 1} -
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\ln\pars{n \over n - 1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

The second term:
\begin{equation}
c \equiv
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\ln\pars{n \over n - 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\zeta\pars{n + 1} - 1 \over n}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
is related to the
[Alladi-Grinstead Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Alladi-GrinsteadConstant.html) $\ds{\expo{c - 1} = 0.809394020540639\ldots}$ while the sum
$\ds{\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}
{1 \over n}\,\ln\pars{n + 1 \over n - 1}}$ still 'claims' for a 'closed form'.
Similarly, by expanding $\ds{\ln\pars{n \over n - 1}}$ in powers of
$\ds{n^{-1}}$, $\pars{1}$ becomes
$$
\,\mathcal{S} =
\ln\pars{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
2\,{\zeta\pars{2n} - 1 \over 2n - 1} - {\zeta\pars{n + 1} - 1 \over n}} =
-\ln\pars{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
{2\zeta\pars{2n} \over 2n - 1} - {\zeta\pars{n + 1} \over n}}
$$

Comment: Felix Marin: I believe that this:

$$c \equiv
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\ln\pars{n \over n - 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\zeta\pars{n} - 1 \over n}\tag{2}$$

should be 

$$c \equiv
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\ln\pars{n \over n - 1} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\zeta\pars{n+1} - 1 \over n}\tag{2}$$

No?

Comment: .... because otherwise we have:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(n)-1}{n}=1-\gamma$$

Comment: @Tolaso Yes. A misprint. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum, maybe some of this will be useful to you:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(1-x) \log (1-x)}{x \log x} \, {\rm d}x=$$

$$=1.2577468869\dots= \gamma_{1}(1,0) - \gamma=\int_0^1 \ln (1-x) \ln \left(\ln \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \, dx-\gamma=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (k+1)}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{k})}{k}=\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \zeta(k)}{k-1}=$$

$$= \frac{\pi^2}{4}-1-4\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x}{1+x^{2}} \frac{dx}{e^{\pi x}+1}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}-1-4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{t~dt}{e^{\pi \tan t}+1} =$$

$$=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln ([x]+1)}{x^2}dx=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\log x+\Gamma (0,x) + \gamma}{e^x-1}~dx$$

Among the sources of the above expressions are:

http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/kz3.pdf

http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/kz.pdf

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/factorial.pdf

https://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=1.2577468869&source=bl

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065075/269624

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1733543/269624