# Conjecture $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n+2)}{n\,(n+1)}\,\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\,{\large\int}_0^1\frac{x\,(\ln x-1)}{\ln(1-x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, closed-form

Numerical calculations suggest that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n+2)}{n\,(n+1)}\,\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\,\int_0^1\frac{x\,(\ln x-1)}{\ln(1-x)}\,dx=1.553767373413083673460727...$$
How can we prove it? Is there a closed form expression for this value?

Comment: Did you try to chop up the integral into pieces and match every term in your series to a piece? E.g. for which $t\in (0,1)$ we have the integral from $t$ to $1$ or from $0$ to $t$ equal to $\frac{ln(3)}{2}$?

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives a slightly smaller value for LHS, 1.52239, where it gives your result for the RHS

Comment: @E.Girgin That is odd. When I calculate the LHS in _Mathematica_, I get the number shown in my question.

Comment: Maybe Wolframalpha is not reliable enough.

Comment: I agree that $RHS=LHS$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Did you write that equation as $\color{red}{R}HS=\color{red}{L}HS$ (as opposed to writing it the **correct way**) on purpose just to offend the sensibilities of pedants like me? =)

Comment: @DavidH: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pater_la_bourgeoisie :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)
$$ \log(n+2)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-(n+1)x}}{xe^x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence by multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and summing over $n\geq 1$ we get:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+2)}{n(n+1)}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-x})\left(1-\log(1-e^{-x})\right)}{xe^x}\,dx\tag{2} $$
then, by substituting $x=-\log(u)$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+2)}{n(n+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(u-1)\left(1-\log(1-u)\right)}{\log(u)}\,du\tag{3} $$
and the claim follows by substituting $v=(1-u)$.

---

I do not think there is a nice closed form but in terms of a derivative of some special zeta function, due to $\log(n+2) = \left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}(n+2)^{\alpha}\right|_{\alpha=0^+}$, but for sure
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-x}{\log(1-x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\log x}\,dx = \log 2$$
and the Taylor series of $\frac{x}{\log(1-x)}$ depends on [Gregory coefficients](https://oeis.org/A002206).

Comment: Shouldn't that be du in (3)?

Comment: @PaulLeVan: yep, fixed.

Comment: Please can you add a comment with your function $f(x)$ in **Frullani's theorem**. I know what are $a$ and $b$ but now not $f$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user243301: In the application of Frullani's theorem in this answer we have $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $a = 1, b = n + 2$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wrong with my triple $(f,a,b)$. Very thanks @ParamanandSingh

Answer (score 4):

Additionnally, by applying Theorem $2$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569)), one obtains a closed form in terms of the [poly-Stieltjes constants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569).

**Proposition**. We have

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1\frac{x\,(\ln x-1)}{\ln(1-x)}\,dx= \ln 2+\gamma_1(2,0)-\gamma_1(1,0)
> \tag1
> \\\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n+2)}{n\,(n+1)}=\ln 2+\gamma_1(2,0)-\gamma_1(1,0)
> \tag2
> \end{align}$$

where

> $$
> \gamma_1(a,b) = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right).
> $$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

`Another possible integral representation`:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{n + 2} \over n\pars{n + 1}}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over 1 + \pars{n + 1}t}}}
^{\ds{\ln\pars{n + 2}}}
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 2 + 1/t}\pars{n + 1}}\,{\dd t \over t} =
\int_{0}^{1}
{\Psi\pars{2 + 1/t} - \Psi\pars{1} \over 1 + 1/t}\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{t\ \to 1/t}{=}\
\color{#f00}{\int_{1}^{\infty}
{\Psi\pars{2 + t} - \Psi\pars{1} \over t + 1}\,{\dd t \over t} =
\gamma\ln\pars{2} + \int_{1}^{\infty}
{\Psi\pars{2 + t} \over t\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t}
\end{align}