# Integral ${\large\int}_0^\infty\big(2J_0(2x)^2+2Y_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2-Y_0(x)^2\big)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, bessel-functions

I'm interested in the following definite integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\big(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2+2Y_0(2x)^2-Y_0(x)^2\big)\,dx,\tag1$$
where $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ are the Bessel functions of the [first](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and the [second](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) kind.

[*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) evaluates this integral symbolically to $\frac{\ln2}\pi$, but the result of a numerical integration looks more like $\frac{\ln4}\pi$, so I suspect the symbolic result is incorrect.

Moreover, it looks like both components converge and make equal contribution:
$$\int_0^\infty\big(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\big)\,dx\stackrel?=\int_0^\infty\big(2Y_0(2x)^2-Y_0(x)^2\big)\,dx\stackrel?=\frac{\ln2}\pi,\tag2$$
but it is more difficult to check numerically, because both integrands here are oscillating (unlike $(1)$ where the integrand looks monotonic).

How can we find values of these integrals and prove them correct? Can we generalize results for values of the index $\nu$ other than $0$?

Comment: When a symbolic integrator returns an incorrect value for a high-brow integral of special functions that *just happens* to be off by an exact integer factor, I would suspect a discrepancy in the internal function definitions being called.

Comment: It is useful to exploit the fact that the Laplace transform of $J_0^2$ is given by a complete elliptic integral of the first kind. I am able to prove that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left( 2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\,dx = \frac{\log 2}{\pi}$ this way, but the $Y_0$ function still eludes me. I will work on this tomorrow.

Comment: I suspect that the same result holds for $0\le\nu<1/2$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I stated an interesting thing in the comments (wisely explored by Random Variable), but it is definitely not the fastest way to go.

For the glory of Italian mathematicians, [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) is the way ([again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805030/conjecture-sum-n-1-infty-frac-lnn2n-n1-stackrel-colorgray)):

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\, J_0(x)^2-2x\, J_0(2x)^2}{x}\,dx = (-\log 2)\cdot\underset{x\to+\infty}{\widetilde{\lim}} x\cdot J_0(x)^2 = \color{red}{-\frac{\log 2}{\pi}} $$
>   and the argument is just the same for the $Y_0$ function.

The wide tilde-limit has to be intended as a Cesàro mean:
$$\underset{x\to+\infty}{\widetilde{\lim}}f(x) = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}f(z)\,dz.$$

Moreover, provided that the integral converges, the previous result holds unchanged also by replacing $J_0$ with $J_\nu$ for any $\nu\geq 0$, since:
$$ J_\nu(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\left(\cos \left(z-\frac{\nu\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) $$
for any large $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Wait, why is Frullani's theorem applicable to a Cesàro mean limit?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: because Frullani's theorem is just a consequence of integration by parts. To say the truth, I am using a slightly strengthened version of the linked result, that allows us to compute also integrals like $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos^2(ax)-\cos^2(bx)}{x}\,dx $$ where the function of interest is oscillating.

Comment: Anyhow, differentiation under the integral sign / Feynman's trick also proves that the main equality in my answer holds true.

Comment: There is also an asymptotic expansion argument: for moderately large values of $x$, $x\cdot J_0(x)^2$ and $\frac{1+\sin(2x)}{\pi}$ are almost the same function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You wrote: "the … result holds unchanged … for any $\nu\ge0$". It looks that integrals with $Y_\nu$ terms  for $\nu\ge1/2$ become divergent near the lower bound $x=0$. You probably meant to add "provided that the integral converges". This is a prerequisite for applying Frullani's theorem, right?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: oh, sure, you are completely right.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The Cesàro mean come from the form of the Frullani's theorem you used, am I right?

Comment: @MarcoCantarini: yes, you are.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE: I added a proof showing that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(2J_{0}(2x)^{2} -J_{0}(x)^2 \right) \, \mathrm dx= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(2Y_{0}(2x)^2 - Y_{0}(x)^{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx. $$

---

We can use [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) to show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx = \frac{\ln 2}{\pi}. $$

As $x \to \infty$, $$\left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right) \sim \frac{\sin (4x)-\sin (2x)}{\pi x}. $$ So the integral converges conditionally but not absolutely.

The [hypergeometric representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/06/01/04/02/01/0004/) of the square of the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero is $$J_{0}(z)^{2} = \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -z^{2} \right). $$

So for $a>0$ and $0 < s < 1$, the Mellin transform of $J_{0}(ax)^{2}$  is $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} J_{0}(ax)^{2} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -(ax)^{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2a^{s}}\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{s/2-1} \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -u \right) \, \mathrm du \\ &= \frac{1}{2a^{s}} \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2} \right) \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2} \right) \Gamma(1)^{2} }{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(1- \frac{s}{2} \right)^{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2a^{s}}  \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2} \right) \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2} \right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma\left(1- \frac{s}{2} \right)^{2}} . \end{align}$$

Since $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx $ converges, a [property of the Mellin transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4235459/16033) allows us to conclude that $$ \begin{align} \lim_{s \to 1^{-}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx &=  \int_{0}^{\infty}  \left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{s \to 1^{-}} \left(\frac{1}{2^{s}}- \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{s}{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{s \to 0^{-}} \left( \frac{1}{2^{s+1}} - \frac{1}{2} \right)\Gamma \left(- \frac{s}{2} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{s \to 0^{-}} \left(- \frac{\ln 2}{2} s + \mathcal{O}(s^{2}) \right) \left(- \frac{2}{s} + \mathcal{O}(1) \right) \\ &= \frac{\ln 2}{\pi}. \end{align}$$

---

Let $H_{0}^{(1)}(z) $ be the [Hankel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Hankel_functions:_H(1)%CE%B1,_H(2)%CE%B1) of the first kind of order zero defined as $$H_{0}^{(1)}(z) = J_{0}(z)+iY_{0}(z). $$

To show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2J_0(2x)^2-J_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx$$  and $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2Y_0(2x)^2-Y_0(x)^2\right)\, \mathrm dx $$ have the same value, we can integrate the function $$2\left( H_{0}^{(1)}(2z)\right)^{2}-\left(H_{0}^{(1)}(z) \right)^{2}$$ around a closed, semicircular contour in the upper half-plane that is indented at the origin.

Applying Jordan's lemma, we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( 2\left( H_{0}^{(1)}(2xe^{i \pi})\right)^{2}-\left(H_{0}^{(1)}(xe^{i \pi} ) \right)^{2} + 2\left( H_{0}^{(1)}(2x)\right)^{2}-\left(H_{0}^{(1)}(x) \right)^{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx = 0. \tag{1}$$

Since $$H_{0}^{(1)}(xe^{i \pi}) = -J_{0}(x)+iY_{0}(x) \, , \quad x >0, $$
we can rewrite $(1)$ as $$2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(2J_{0}(2x)^{2} -J_{0}(x)^2-2Y_{0}(2x)^2 + Y_{0}(x)^{2} \right) = 0, $$ and the result follows.

Comment: (+1) Very interesting approach. What about the $Y_0^2$ function?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks.  I'm still trying to figure out how to deal with the other integral.

Comment: When persuing almost the same path, I got that the Laplace transform of $Y_0^2$ is given by the difference between an elliptic integral and a $$\phantom{}_3 F_2\left(1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};z\right)$$ function. Maybe that helps and sheds some light on peculiar properties of such a hypergeometric function.