# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n) -\ln(n+1)}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

The sum series exercise started as: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{\left(n+1\right)^n}\right)}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\ln\frac{n}{n+1}}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n) - \ln(n+1)}{n+1}$$
Looking into calculating it.
A quick hint will help me out!

Comment: Please what is the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am looking into calculating it.

Comment: A numerical approximation or a closed form?

Comment: Whatever of both is going to help me. Even giving me hints like "steps.. and a telescope series"

Comment: Use the comparison test

Comment: Convergence of the series is direct; the value of its sum, though, is not obvious. What makes you think it can be computed?

Comment: It can be computed, because its on my exercise book of my University.

Comment: Im studying some quick exercises that our Series teacher gave us for Christmas (Im in Kapodistrian University of Athens at Mathematics department). The exercise just says: Calculate: and the sum of the first part my question above.

Comment: Perhaps try to view this sum as a reimann sum of an integral (Probably improper )

Comment: @Sar No, he just want us with tricks and stuff to end to a telescope series. Olivier gave a perfect answer that Im digging into to find out a faster solution.

Comment: "Calculate" seems to refer to expressing this series as the value of a rather unusual function defined as... a series rather closely related to the initial ones. One can have doubts about the usefulness of the exercise and the understanding it helps to acquire.

Comment: @Did exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n \to \infty$, the general term of the series satisfies
$$
\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)}{n(n+1)}=-\frac{1}{n+1}\ln{\small{\left(1+\frac1n\right)}}\sim -\frac1{n^2}
$$
giving the convergence of the series.

From
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln n-\ln(n+1)}{n+1}
$$ one may use [Theorem 2 (16)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569) to get a closed form in terms of poly-Stieltjes constants:

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)}{n(n+1)}=\gamma_1(0,1)-\gamma_1 \tag1
> $$

where
$$
\gamma_1(a,b) = \lim_{N\to+\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\log (n+a)}{n+b}-\frac{\log^2 \!N}2\right)
$$
and $\gamma_1=\gamma_1(1,1)$ is an ordinary [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

By using Mathematica, one gets

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}\right)}{n(n+1)}=-0.7885205660\cdots. \tag2
> $$

Comment: Awesome! Thanks

Comment: Why can't we use telescoping series method for this sum?

Comment: Please, I'm not sure I get your point. Do you mean you can obtain a closed form with a telescoping series?