# How to compute the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{\ln (1-x)}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> How to compute the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{\ln (1-x)}dx$?

We can write 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{\ln (1-x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{(1-u)\ln (1-u)}{\ln u}du
=-\int_0^1\frac{1-u}{\ln u}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n}du
\end{align*}
Seeing
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{u^{a-1}-u^{b-1}}{\ln u}du=\ln\frac{a}{b},\forall a,b>0,
\end{align*}
we get 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{\ln (1-x)}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{n+2}{n+1}.
\end{align*}
I have tried hard to compute the series above ,but without any progress.

Comment: I got the same summation but according to Wolf it's off by about 0.05 from the integral.  Strange.  Maybe because the domain of convergence of the maclaurin series of $\ln{1-x}$ is $x<1$ and the upper bound is $1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evalute $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log x}{\log(1-x)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299309/how-to-evalute-int-01-fracx-log-x-log1-xdx) (Found with the help of [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Cln%20x%7D%7B%5Cln%5Cleft(1-x%5Cright)%7D%24%2C%20integral%2C%20integration%2C%20closed-form&p=1)). It appears as there might be no known closed-form.

Answer (score 1):

One thig we could do is to expand as series
$$\frac{x}{\log (1-x)}=-1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{19 x^4}{720}+\frac{3
   x^5}{160}+\frac{863 x^6}{60480}+\frac{275 x^7}{24192}+\frac{33953
   x^8}{3628800}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ where the coefficients correspond to the absolute value of [Gregory  coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients), that is to say
$$\frac{x \log (x)}{\log (1-x)}=-\log(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty |G_n| x^n \log(x)$$ Integrating termwise
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x)}{\log (1-x)}\,dx=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty |G_n|\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}$$ which generates the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{7}{8},\frac{187}{216},\frac{2983}{3456},\frac{372419}{432000},\frac{
   186097}{216000},\frac{1994053}{2315250},\frac{2721985571}{3161088000},\frac{1984
   061289739}{2304433152000},\cdots\right\}$$ which seems to converge quite fast.