# Searching for closed-form solutions to integral of dilogarithm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, summation

while trying to evaluate an infinite sum, I came across this integral:
$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{I}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\DeclareMathOperator{\dilog}{Li_{2}}\dilog\left(-e^{-x}\right)\mathrm dx\tag*{}$$
Its approximate value by Wolfram is:
$$\approx -0.694981$$
This looks similar to a Feynman Trick integral, so I'm wondering if there's a possible parameter we could use to simplify this integral somehow. Honestly, closed-form is going to be a very lax term in regards to this integral. I *think* a possible solution could be in terms of Gamma functions of complex arguments, or similarly a solution viz. Stieltjes constants (generalized Stieltjes more likely). I'm curious to see what you guys have in mind.

Notice, this integral was derived as part of an expression for a solution to the following infinite series:
$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k}\arctan(k)}{k^{2}}=-\frac{\pi}{4}\zeta(2)-\mathcal{I}$$
If you'd like to tackle this infinite sum as well, go right ahead! It's pretty interesting. One thing I haven't tried so far but could be of use is the fact that $$(-1)^{k}=\cos(\pi k)$$ and possibly differentiate the sum and see if I could build either a differential equation or find a simpler form with a closed-form solution that could then be integrated back. 
Good Luck to you and thank you in advance for taking the time to explore this integral and sum with me!

Comment: Any particular reason why the sum doesn't start at $k=1$?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art This is how the sum was originally presented to me. I agree that it's just an added nuisance, so I will shift the index for this sum as it bares no conflict to its convergence.

Comment: Well, I differentiated the sum and got some silly $$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\frac{4\pi x^2}{1+x^2})}{\cos(\frac{4\pi x^2}{1+x^2})-\cosh(\frac{4\pi x}{1+x^2})}+\dots~\mathrm dx$$ so... is this supposed to be solvable?

Comment: It could very well be a lost cause. I hoped maybe we could express this sum at least in terms of some existing transcendental functions. There was [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569) by Olivier Oloa in which he devised the notion of "Poly-Stieltjes coefficients" which can be used to find a closed-form for this sum in terms of those coefficients. But they are a fairly new thing, can't find any other literature on them. So I wondered if the solution could be formed in terms of more popular functions.