# $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(k)}{k^2(k+1)}$ explicit value.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to evaluate the following series explicitly, 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(k)}{k^2(k+1)}$$
I know this converges by the comparison test.
I have tried defining a function,
$$f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(kt)}{k^2(k+1)}$$
Differentiating this with respect to t gives,
$$f'(t)=\frac{1}{t}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)} = \frac{1}{t}(\zeta(2)-1)$$
Integrating this,
$$\int_a^t f'(s)ds = f(t)-f(a) = (\zeta(2)-1)(\log(t) - \log(a))$$
for some constant a>0. However whichever constant I choose I get in a bit of a muddle when trying to evaluate at t=1. I was hoping for a hint in the right direction or maybe a suggestion of a different method that might be useful.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5E%28infinity%29+log%28k%29%2F%28k%5E3%2Bk%5E2%29) returns nothing. This is not a good sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given series admits a closed form in terms of the *poly-Stieltjes constants* defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569). By using the absolute convergence, on may write 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(k)}{k^2(k+1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(k)}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(k)}{k(k+1)}
=-\zeta'(2)-\gamma_1+\gamma_1(0,1),
\end{align} having applied [Theorem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569) to the latter series.

Comment: According to Mathematica: $$\zeta '(2)=\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 (-12 \log (A)+\gamma +\log (2)+\log (\pi )),$$ where $A$ is Glaisher's Constant and $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.