# How can i find ${I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^{2n}\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)^n}}dx{,n} \in N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Question:- Find ${I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^{2n}\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)^n}}dx{,n} \in N}$

Recently I asked a similar question
$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)}}dx=\frac{-π^2}{16(2+\sqrt{2})}$

Below the above question a note is  written as follows:

'The reader should evaluate the family of integrals ${I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^{2n}\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)^n}}dx{,n} \in N}$ .The computation of the first few special values indicates an interesting arithmetic structure of the answer.’

I don't know how to tackle ${I_{n}}$ till now.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:-** Here is the link for above document
http://emmy.uprrp.edu/lmedina/papers/part27/final27.pdf

I have searched all the references mentioned in above document but found nothing related to above integral.We might have to look values for different values of $n$ instead of finding integral for general $n$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For $n=2$ I tried partial fraction then i write series for some terms but integrals does not look nice to compute.Some integrals involves use of digamma function and its derivative but some are difficult to compute. Also for some other n partial fraction does not work as no of terms are large

Comment: For n=2 mathematica says the value is $\frac{1}{128} \pi  \left(\pi  \left(\sqrt{2}-4\right)+4 \sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: What is the source of the text above?

Comment: @FDP these are the papers from The American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: @Paras: Please what is the exact source? (volume/year, number)

Comment: What about recursive relation? ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The task standing.}}$

Firstly,
\begin{cases}
{\Large\int} \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{2t^2+1} = \dfrac{\arctan t\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}+\mathrm{const}\\[4pt]
{\Large\int} \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{(2t^2+1)^{k}} = \dfrac{t}{2(k-1)(2t^2+1)^{k-1}} 
+\dfrac{2k-3}{2k-2}{\Large\int} \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{(2t^2+1)^{k-1}}\quad (k=2,3\dots)\\[4pt]
R_k = {\Large\int}_0^\infty \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{(2t^2+1)^{k}} = \dfrac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k-2)!!}\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}8\quad (k=2,3\dots),\quad R_1 = \dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}4.\tag1
\end{cases}

Also, is known [integral representation of the trigamma function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/07/01/01/) in the form of
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\,e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}\mathrm dt
= \psi^{(1)}(z),$$
then
\begin{align}
&J_{k ,l} = \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\,\cosh kt}{\sinh lt}\mathrm dt
= \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\,(e^{-(l+k)t}+e^{-(l-k)t})}{1-e^{-2lt}}\mathrm dt
= \dfrac1{4l^2}\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\,\Big(e^{^{\Large\!-\frac{l+k}{2l}t}}+e^{^{\Large\!-\frac{l-k}{2l}t}}\Big)}{1-e^{-t}}\mathrm dt\\[4pt]
&= \dfrac{1}{4l^2}\left(\psi^{(1)}\left(\dfrac{l+k}{2l}\right)
+\psi^{(1)}\left(\dfrac{l-k}{2l}\right)\right)
= \dfrac{\pi^2}{4l^2\sin^2\dfrac{l-k}{2l}\pi},
\end{align}

$$J_{k,l}= \dfrac{\pi^2}{2l^2\left(1+\cos\dfrac kl\pi\right)}.\tag2$$

At last, substituion $x=e^{-t}$ presents the given integral in the form of

$$I_n=\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{x^{2n}\,\ln x\,\mathrm dx}{(1-x^2)(1+x^4)^n} 
= -\dfrac1{2^{n+1}} \hat I_n,\quad \hat I_n =\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\,\mathrm dt}{\sinh t\cosh^n2t}.\tag3$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Starting values.}}$

Taking in account $(1)-(3)$, one can get
$$\hat I_0 = J_{0,1} = \dfrac12\psi^{(1)}\left(\dfrac{1}2\right) = \dfrac{\pi^2}4,\tag{4.1}$$
$$I_0 = -\dfrac12 \hat I_0 = -\dfrac{\pi^2}8 
\approx -1.23370\,05501\,36170\tag{4.2}$$
(in accordance with the [Wolfram Alpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20ln%20x%2F%281-x%5E2%29%20dx)),

$$\hat I_1 = \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\cosh t\,\mathrm dt}{\sinh t \cosh t \cosh 2t}
= 4\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\cosh t\,\mathrm dt}{\sinh 4t} = 4J_{1,4},$$
$$\hat I_1 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{8\left(1+\cos\dfrac \pi4\right)} = \dfrac{\pi^2(2-\sqrt2)}8,\tag{5.1}$$
$$I_1=-\dfrac14\hat I_1 = -\dfrac{\pi^2(2-\sqrt2)}{32} = \approx -0.18067\,12625\,90655\tag{5.2}$$
([numeric calculations give](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20x%5E2%20ln%20x%2F%281-x%5E2%2Bx%5E4-x%5E6%29%20dx) $I_1 \approx -0.18067\,1$),

\begin{align}
&\hat I_2 = \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t}{\sinh t\cosh^2 2t}\,\mathrm dt
= \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t}{\sinh t}\,\mathrm d\tanh 2t
\,\overset{IBP}{=\!=\!=}\, 
\dfrac{t\tanh 2t}{2\sinh t}\bigg|_0^\infty
\hspace{-80mu}\mathbf{\LARGE_{_\diagup\hspace{-11mu}\diagup}\hspace{3mu}^\diagup}\\[4pt]
&-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{\sinh t - t\cosh t}{\sinh^2 t}
\,\dfrac{2\sinh t \cosh t}{\cosh 2t} \,\mathrm dt
= -\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\cosh t\,\mathrm dt}{2\sinh^2t+1}
+ \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\cosh^2 t}{\sinh t\cosh 2t}\,\mathrm dt\\[4pt]
&= -R_1+ \dfrac12\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t(1+\cosh 2t)}{\sinh t\cosh 2t}\,\mathrm dt
= - \dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}4+\dfrac12(\hat I_1+\hat I_0),
\end{align}
$$\hat I_2 = -\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}4 + \dfrac{\pi^2(4-\sqrt2)}{16},\tag{6.1}$$
$$I_2 = \dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}{32}-\dfrac{\pi^2(4-\sqrt2)}{128}\approx -0.06054\,02925\,97236\tag{6.2}$$
([numeric calculations give](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20x%5E4%20ln%20x%2F%28%281-x%5E2%29%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E2%29%20dx) $I_2 \approx -0.06054\,03$).

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Recurrence approach.}}$

If $m\ge2,$ then
\begin{align}
&\hat I_{m+1} = \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t}{\sinh t\cosh^{m+1}2t}\,\mathrm dt
= \dfrac1{2}\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t}{\sinh t\cosh^{m-1} 2t}\,\mathrm d\tanh 2t\\[4pt]
&\,\overset{IBP}{=\!=\!=}\, 
\dfrac{t\tanh 2t}{2\sinh t\cosh^{m-1} 2t}\bigg|_0^\infty
\hspace{-120mu}\mathbf{\LARGE_{_\diagup\hspace{-11mu}\diagup}\hspace{3mu}^\diagup} \hspace{80mu}\\[4pt]
&-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\infty\Biggl(\dfrac{2\sinh t\cosh t}{\sinh t\cosh^m 2t} -\dfrac{2t\sinh t\cosh^2 t}{\sinh^2 t\cosh^m 2t}-\dfrac{2(m-1)t\sinh^2 2t}{\sinh t\cosh^{m+1} 2t}\Biggr)\,\mathrm dt\\[4pt]
&= -\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\cosh t\,\mathrm dt}{(2\sinh^2t+1)^m}
+\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\cosh^2 t}{\sinh t\cosh^{m} 2t}\,\mathrm dt
+ (m-1)\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t\sinh^2 2t}{\sinh t\cosh^{m+1} 2t}\,\mathrm dt\\[4pt]
&= -R_m + \dfrac12\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t(1+\cosh 2t)}{\sinh t\cosh^m 2t}\,\mathrm dt
+ (m-1)\int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac{t(\cosh^2 2t-1)}{\sinh t\cosh^{m+1} 2t}\,\mathrm dt,\\[4pt]
&\hat I_{m+1}= -\dfrac{(2m-3)!!}{2^{m+1}(m-1)!}\pi\sqrt2 - (m-1)\hat I_{m+1} +\dfrac12I_{m}+\dfrac{2m-1}2\hat I_{m-1},
\end{align}

$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\hat I_{m+1}= -\dfrac{(2m-3)!!}{(2m)!!}\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}4 + \dfrac1{2m}\hat I_{m}+\dfrac{2m-1}{2m}\hat I_{m-1}.}}\tag7$$
In particular,
$$\hat I_3 = -\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}{16}+\left(-\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}{16}+\dfrac{\pi^2(4-\sqrt2)}{64}\right)-\dfrac{3\pi^2(2-\sqrt2)}{32},$$
$$\hat I_3 = -\dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}{8}+\dfrac{\pi^2(16-7\sqrt2)}{64},\tag{8.1}$$
$$I_3 = \dfrac{\pi\sqrt2}{128}-\dfrac{\pi^2(16-7\sqrt2)}{1024}\approx -0.02408\,83868\,33221\tag{8.2}$$
([numeric calculations give](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20x%5E6%20ln%20x%2F%28%281-x%5E2%29%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E3%29%20dx) $I_3 -\approx 0.02408\,84$).

Finally, the table of the [obtained values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Ba%28m%2B1%29%3D%20-1%2F2%20%282m-3%29%21%21%2F%282m%29%21%21%20pi%20sqrt2%20%2B%20a%28m%29%2F%282m%29%2B%282m-1%29%20a%28m-1%29%20%2F%282m%29%2C%20a%282%29%20%3D%20-pi%2F4%20sqrt%202%20%2B%20pi%5E2%20%284-%20sqrt2%29%2F16%2C%20a%283%29%20%3D%20-pi%2F8%20sqrt%202%20%2Bpi%5E2%2816-7%20sqrt2%29%20%2F64%7D) is below.

\begin{vmatrix}
m  & \hat I_m & I_m\\
2  & 0.484322 & -0.06054\,03 \\
3  & 0.385414 & -0.02408\,838 \\
4  & 0.328998 & -0.01028\,119 \\
5  & 0.291587 & -0.00455\,6047 \\
6  & 0.264514 & -0.00206\,6516 \\
7  & 0.243774 & -0.00095\,2242 \\
8  & 0.227238 & -0.00044\,38242 \\
9  & 0.213657 & -0.00020\,86494 \\
10 & 0.202247 & -0.00009\,87534\,2 \\
11 & 0.192486 & -0.00004\,699365\tag9
\end{vmatrix}

The data of table $(9)$ correspond to the direct calculations of the given integral.

For example, [numeric calculations give](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20%28x%5E14%20ln%20x%29%2F%28%281-x%5E2%29%281%2Bx%5E4%29%5E7%29%20dx) $$I_7 \approx 0.00095\,2242,$$

This **confirms** obtained formulas and the result structure in the common case.

Answer (score 13):

$$ I_n = \int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1-x^2} \cdot \frac{x^{2n}}{(1+x^4)^n} dx$$

Note that $\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(1-x^2)(1+x^4)^n}$ is written as $$ \frac{x^{2n}}{(1-x^2)(1+x^4)^n} = \frac{1}{2^{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2} -\frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{p_n(x)}{(1+x^4)^n}$$
where $p_n$ is some polynomial satisfying
\begin{align*}
p_n(x) &= \frac{ (1+x^4)^n - 2^n x^{2n}}{ (1-x^2)}\\ 
&  =\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \sum_{j = 0}^{(n-1)/2} \binom{n}{j}\left(x^{4j} -2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}\right) & \text{for $n$ odd}\\
    \frac{1}{1-x^2} \cdot \sum_{j = 0}^{n/2-1} \binom{n}{j}\left(x^{4j} -2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}\right)  & \text{for $n$ even}
  \end{cases}\\
& =  \sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{j} \frac{x^{4j} -2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}}{1-x^2}
\end{align*}

Note that $x^{4j} - 2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j} = (x^{2j} - x^{2n-2j})^2 = x^{4j} (1 - x^{2n-4j})^2$, so 
\begin{align*}
    \frac{x^{4j} - 2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}}{1-x^2} &= (x^{4j}-x^{2n})\cdot \frac{1-x^{2n-4j}}{1-x^2} \\
    & =  (x^{4j}-x^{2n})\cdot (1 + x^2 + \cdots + x^{2n-4j-2}) \\
    & = (x^{4j} + x^{4j+2} + \cdots + x^{2n-2}) - (x^{2n} + x^{2n+2} + \cdots + x^{4n-4j -2})\\
    & = \sum_{k = 2j}^{n-1}(x^{2k} - x^{4n - 2k -2})
\end{align*}
Consider the following integral
$$J(n,k) = \int_0^1\frac{x^{2k} - x^{4n-2k-2}}{(1+x^4)^n}\log(x) dx$$
which is defined for $n\ge 1$ and $0 \le k \le n-1$. Then we have
\begin{align*}2^n I_n & = \int_0^1\frac{\log x}{1-x^2} dx - \int_0^1 \frac{p_n(x)}{(1+x^4)^n}\log x dx \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{8}  - \int_0^1  \sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j}\frac{x^{4j} -2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}}{(1-x^2)(1+x^4)^n}\log x  dx \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{8}  -\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j} \int_0^1   \frac{x^{4j} -2x^{2n} + x^{4n-4j}}{(1-x^2)(1+x^4)^n} \log x dx \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{8}  -\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j} \int_0^1  \frac{1}{(1+x^4)^n} \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} (x^{2k} - x^{4n-2k-2}) \log x dx \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{8}  -\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j}  \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2k} - x^{4n-2k-2}}{(1+x^4)^n} \log x dx \\
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{8} -\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j}  \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} J(n, k)
\end{align*}
so we are reduced to find $J(n, k)$ values.

\begin{align*} J(n, k) & = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2k}}{(1+x^4)^n}\log x dx - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{4n-2k-2}}{(1+x^4)^n} \log x dx \\
& \stackrel{ x= 1/u}{=} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2k}}{(1+x^4)^n}\log x dx - \int_\infty^1 \frac{u^{-4n+2k+2}}{(1+u^{-4})^n} \log u\frac{du}{u^2}\\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{2k}}{(1+x^4)^n}\log x dx +\int_1^\infty \frac{u^{2k}}{(1+u^{4})^n} \log udu \\
& =\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(1+x^4)^n}\log x dx  \\
\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a}}{(1+x^4)^n} dx & \stackrel{x^4 = w}{=} \frac{1}{4} B\left(\frac{a+1}{4}, n - \frac{a+1}{4}\right)\\
& = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(n - \frac{a+1}{4} \right)}{4\Gamma(n)}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a}}{(1+x^4)^n} dx & = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{x^{a}}{(1+x^4)^n} =  \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a}\log x}{(1+x^4)^n} dx \\
    & = \frac{1}{4 \Gamma(n)} \frac{d}{da}\left( \Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left( n - \frac{a+1}{4}\right)\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{4 \Gamma(n)} \left( \Gamma\left( \frac{a+1}{4}\right) \frac{d}{da} \Gamma\left(n - \frac{a+1}{4} \right) + \Gamma\left(n - \frac{a+1}{4} \right) \frac{d}{da} \Gamma\left( \frac{a+1}{4}\right) \right) \\
& =  \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{a+1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(n - \frac{a+1}{4} \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left(  \psi \left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right) - \psi \left(n - \frac{a+1}{4}\right) \right) \\
\end{align*}
For convenience let $\alpha = \frac{a+1}{4}$ and proceed as 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{da} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{(1+x^4)^n} dx & =\frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha\right) \Gamma\left(n - \alpha \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left( \psi(\alpha) - \psi (n - \alpha)\right) \\
 %& =\frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha\right) \Gamma\left(n - \alpha \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left( \psi(\alpha) - \psi (1 - \alpha) - \frac{1}{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{2-\alpha} - \cdots - \frac{1}{n-1-\alpha} \right) \\
 & =\frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha\right) \Gamma\left(n - \alpha \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left( \psi(\alpha) - \psi (1 - \alpha) -  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\alpha}  \right) \\
 & = -\frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha\right) \Gamma\left(n - \alpha \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left( \pi \cot \pi \alpha +  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\alpha}  \right) \\ 
 & =  -\frac{\Gamma\left( \alpha\right) \Gamma\left(1 - \alpha \right) }{16 \Gamma(n)} \left( \pi \cot \pi \alpha +  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\alpha}  \right)\left( (n-1 - \alpha) \cdots (1-\alpha)\right)\\ 
 & =  -\frac{\pi \csc \pi \alpha}{16(n-1)!} \left( \pi \cot \pi \alpha +  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\alpha}  \right)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(m-\alpha)\\ 
\end{align*}
Finally we have 
\begin{align*}
J(n, k) & = -\frac{\pi \csc \frac{\pi(2k+1)}{4}}{16(n-1)!} \left( \pi \cot \frac{\pi(2k+1)}{4}+  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\frac{2k+1}{4}}  \right)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(m-\frac{2k+1}{4}\right) \\ 
& =  -\frac{\pi \sqrt{2} (-1)^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}}{16(n-1)!} \left( \pi (-1)^k+  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\frac{2k+1}{4}}  \right)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(m-\frac{2k+1}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

and 
\begin{align*} 2^n I_n  &=-\frac{\pi^2}{8} -\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j}  \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} J(n, k) \\
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{8} +\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{j}  \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} \frac{\pi \sqrt{2} (-1)^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}}{16(n-1)!} \left( \pi (-1)^k+  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\frac{2k+1}{4}}  \right)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(m-\frac{2k+1}{4}\right) \\
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{8} +\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi n}{16}\sum_{j = 0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \frac{1}{j!(n-j)!} \sum_{k=2j}^{n-1} (-1)^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \left( \pi (-1)^k+  \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-\frac{2k+1}{4}}  \right)\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(m-\frac{2k+1}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Which is verified for some $n$'s by Mathematica.

I want to figure out the 'interesting arithmetic structure' but I cannot see. Can anybody simplify this to illuminate the arithmetic structure?

Comment: Calculating the first value of $I_n$ i don't think there is a simple arithmetic structure

Comment: What is $I_{3}$  and $I_{4}$ ?