# Integrating $\int^u_0\frac{dx}{x^2+3x+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, problem-solving

> Find $$\int^u_0\frac{dx}{x^2+3x+2}$$

I'm having trouble making progress on this.  Specifically, I know the following means to find an integral:

1. Antiderivative
2. Integration by parts
3. Change of variable
4. Definition of integral (either Darboux or Riemann).

None of these have been helpful to me:

1. $\frac{1}{x^2 + 3x + 2}$ is not the derivative of anything I can construct.  The closest is $\frac{2x + 3}{x^2 + 3x + 2} = [\log (x^2 + 3x + 2)]'$.  This might be useful in combination with another method, so let's keep on looking.
2. I've tried various combinations, such as $u = \frac{1}{x^2 + 3x + 2}, v= x^2 + 3x$ or $u = \log(x^2 + 3x + 2), v = \frac{1}{2x+3}$.  Again, none have gotten me further.
3. $f(x) = 1/x, u(x) = x^2 + 3x +2, u'(x) = 2x$.  The problem is I can't get the $u'(x)$ factor to appear.
4. I've made no progress with the definitions.  In fact, I've only seen definitions used to prove general theorems, never to compute a specific integral.

**Can you point me in the right direction?** Please do *not* post the full solution; just let me know how I need to tackle this.

Comment: This is less of an integration technique and more of an algebraic manipulation, but try partial fraction decomposition: can you rewrite your integrand in terms of a sum of simpler fractions? (try factoring the denominator)

Comment: Have you learned partial-fraction decomposition yet?  The denominator can be factored and the single rational function can be separated into the sum of two simpler ones.

Comment: I think that if you complete the square the results follow

Comment: Read, at your liberty, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/integration-by-partial-fractions-how-and-why-does-it-work) which covers partial fraction decomposition. You can use this to solve questions of the form $\int \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$.

Comment: @BrienNavarro This should work but it's a lot messier than the partial fraction decomposition. I believe  for this type of integral as a general rule of thumb completing the square and going for a trig sub is better when the roots in the denominator are complex.

Comment: For fun you can let $u=\frac{x+1}{x+2}$

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate.  The dupe target is not a precise duplicate, but the relevant technique here is to decompose the integrand via partial fractions, then integrate.  The linked duplicate demonstrates how this can be done.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

You can factor the denominator in order to obtain:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x^{2} + 3x + 2} & = \frac{1}{(x + 1)(x + 2)}\\\\
& = \frac{(x+2) - (x+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, from here it's $\int^u_0{\frac{dx}{x^2 + 3x + 2}} = \log(\frac{2u+2}{u+2})$.

Answer (score 0):

I will just provide the Ansatz for partial fraction decomposition.

You factor by looking for the roots of $x^2+3x+2$, which might be $x_1$ and $x_2$. I use completion of the square.

Then, if we got two different roots $x_i$, you set
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2} = \frac{1}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)} = \frac{C}{x-x_1} + \frac{D}{x-x_2}
$$
and multiply both sides by $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and sort by powers of $x^0 = 1$ and $x^1 = x$ to get a linear system of two equations in the unknowns $C$ and $D$.

After you determined $C$ and $D$ you can continue to integrate the easier two integrals.